# Библиотека curl c++

Tags: curl, c++, библиотеки, visual-studio

Подскажите, как установить библиотеку `curl` для `visual studio`, и где её можно скачать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну неужели так трудно вбить в гуго curl windows? Первый же результат ведёт куда надо

[CURL Releases and Downloads](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) - тут есть сборки для Windows.